# Is it better to keep a fixed bed time or waking up time?

Tags: sleep

As we all know the best is to have fixed bed time and fixed waking up time in order not to feel tired. However life does not always allow this.

If you need to reduce your sleeping time (or at the opposite increase your sleep time during the weekend in order to catch up) is it better to shift the time your going to bed or the waking up time ?
Is one of the two options better in handling these variation of sleeping time or does it make no difference ?

Edit : This question is asked because I have intensive sport trainings (dance+gym(acrobatics)) at fixed time several days and I have to work a given amount of hours (amount which can vary) for my job but I'm free to adjust my timetable (bed/waking up time) as long as I do my job hours. That's why I'm asking when I have a variation of working hour, is one of the two option better in order to be the less tired for sport training.
(However it's true that it may also be applied in general outside of Physical Fitness so maybe it's off topic)

Comment: Is it related in anyway to physical fitness? Can you edit your post to reflect that? Otherwise, it might be closed as *off-topic* .

Comment: Agree with @Kneel-Before-ZOD.  Need to change to be more exercise related or it will be closed as question stands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to get 8 hours sleep a night, and having consistent times you go to bed and wake up help that happen.

- [Poor sleep can undermine any body composition](http://gregnuckols.com/2014/04/09/sleep-pt-1/) changes you are trying to make.
- [Poor sleep causes bad recovery](http://gregnuckols.com/2014/04/28/poor-recovery-and-increased-muscle-breakdown-insufficient-sleep-part-2/) and increased muscle break down.

In an *ideal* world, you would be able to go to bed at a consistent time every night, and naturally get up on time in the morning.  Unfortunately, life does have a way of not being ideal.  If you have to keep odd hours because of work, try to minimize the damage.  This is when you have to prioritize things.  You won't always be able to do everything.  Top priority for working individuals is to get work done.  That means depending on how worn down you are, you may have to skip a training session to get sleep in--or you may have to adjust sleep to get your training in.

This much is true, you can't compromise sleep for long stretches of time.  Whether you keep a consistent bed time or a consistent wake time, if you aren't getting enough sleep you will be just as tired.  It's a lose-lose situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its the best idea to keep a fixed bed time or waking up time.But due to our busy schedule it cant be possible for everyone.Taking enough sleep is very important for our health.It is very hard to main the sleep but we have to do it.Sometimes it is very hard to us to go for sleep at least eight hours because of work tension or personal tension.To fix all these problem you have to do meditation and fix your time of  early to bed and early to rise.